# npm create-react-app command not completing

Tags: reactjs, npm, cmd

npm create-react-app is getting stuck at 0 vulnerabilities found and then it gets stuck after that.. I have to Ctrl+C after that to get out and it does not show any success. For reference stating that below

```
$ npx create-react-app foo                                                                                              
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\Afshan\Desktop\foo.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...


> core-js@2.6.11 postinstall C:\Users\Afshan\Desktop\foo\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Afshan\Desktop\foo\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"


> core-js-pure@3.6.5 postinstall C:\Users\Afshan\Desktop\foo\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

+ react@16.13.1
+ cra-template@1.0.3
+ react-dom@16.13.1
+ react-scripts@3.4.1
added 1605 packages from 750 contributors and audited 931194 packages in 279.386s

58 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the directory if the folder has been created with the necessary files. But if this a recurring issue, it could be your command shell.

Comment: It ha node modules but when i try to run it  the terminal shows ERR about scripts! Working with Hyper .Dont know that it would be command shell issue or not

Comment: It could be your shell. Or try running just `create-react-app foo`. Personally I've found the npx to give me issues sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "resmon" in cmd. Find cmd.exe. If cmd.exe is suspended then select resume process.

Look at this issue on github:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8915